# Keeping activity alive

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I have a series of activities in my application which starts with Activity "A" and followed by "B", "C" , "D" and "E". Activity "A","B","C" and "D" are transparent activities (transparent theme) while "E" is opaque.

The requirement is the Activity "A" should not be finished. I read through a blog http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/01/13/android-activity-life-cycle/ which states that

1. If an activity has lost focus but is still visible (that is, a new
   non-full-sized or transparent activity has focus on top of your
   activity), it is paused.
2. If an activity is completely obscured by another activity, it is
   stopped.

The onStop() of Activity "A" is not called till the user browses to Activity "D" however it is called when Activity "E" is invoked.

Is there anyway that we can keep the Activity "A" running in the Activity stack? Is it a good solution to keep a static reference of the Activity in a Application object so that framework does not kill it ? What precautions can i take so that "A" is not killed? Is there a way that i can get a notification if this gets killed by framework so that i can recreate it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The requirement is the Activity "A" should not be finished.

An activity is finished via a call to `finish()`. This normally happens when the user presses the BACK button.

> The onStop() of Activity "A" is not called till the user browses to Activity "D" however it is called when Activity "E" is invoked.

Correct.

> Is there anyway that we can keep the Activity "A" running in the Activity stack?

It *is* "running" in the activity stack (for any reasonable definition of "running"), until such time as you call `finish()`, the user presses BACK, or the process is terminated. `onStop()` has no impact on that.

> Is it a good solution to keep a static reference of the Activity in a Application object so that framework does not kill it ?

No, because it is not going to help. The activity will remain in memory until such time as you call `finish()`, the user presses BACK, or the process is terminated.

> What precautions can i take so that "A" is not killed?

Do not call `finish()`.

> Is there a way that i can get a notification if this gets killed by framework so that i can recreate it ?

Your activity will be called with `onDestroy()` if it is finished. This may or may not occur if the process is terminated, depending on what triggered the termination and the state of the system at that time.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Murphy. That answers everything.